# After install desktop on ubuntu20.04，Raspberry4B, it can't scan wifi

Tags: pi-4

After installing the desktop in ubuntu20.04 server, wifi cannot be scanned in the system settings, but I can connect wifi by modifying the wifi configuration file under/etc/netplan/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be better-suited to the Ubuntu SE.

Answer (score 0):

It is far from clear what you actually did.

Ubuntu server does not support WiFi.

If you installed Desktop it probably installed Network Manager so you will need to configure networking using nmcli.

You could try the Network Manager GUI plugin in Panel.